# React Context Provide not passing the value to the Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am having the below Provide which contains the authentication state in it.

```
export const AuthenticationContext = React.createContext();

export default class AuthenticationProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I have this wrapped to my Routes as below:

```
     <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <AuthenticationProvider>
              <SiteHeader />
              <ErrorWrapper />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateHomeRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} 
              </Switch>
            </AuthenticationProvider>
          </>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
```

But when I am trying to get context state into the `<SiteHeader />`, there is nothing passed down by the `Context.Provide`. My Cosumer is inside `<SiteHeader />` is:

```
class SiteHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <AuthenticationContext.Consumer>
          {context => (
            <header>this is header {context.state.isAuthenticated}</header>
          )}
        </AuthenticationContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I checked the React devtools, but it's same. `Context.Consumer` doesn't have `value` prop from the `Provider`.

What might be the issue here?
[image: devtools]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a value is false, null or undefined, it will not render. I tried your code in a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q331x2l584). Just added the .toString() in the header, and the value of the boolean is shown in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Context Consumers don't get any data as a props.
instead we pass them a `render prop`, in this case the children that we pass is the render prop function. and then in the render method of the Consumer something like this happens

```
render(){
  this.props.children(value)
}
```

this is how we get the value as an argument of the render prop function.

The value of the context provider is not supposed to be passed in through props. You can learn more about [render props here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Comment: His consumer doesn't rely on props. It's all from the context parameter.

Comment: His question was that the Provider `value` is not passed in to the Consumer as a prop. But that's not how React.Context works. My guess will be he is confusing reander prop with HOC. I can be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it.

Comment: You are welcome if this answer was the one you were looking for kindly accept it so others may easily see which answer is correct to this question